# Spring Boot Application ,JPA,

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jpa, http-status-code-404, tomcat9

I have created a small application using the spring boot framework. I have created a Rest Controler class.
and deploy it on tomcat, but I am getting 404 error i.e
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

```
@RestController
```

@RequestMapping("students")
public class StudentController {

```
@Autowired
StudentRepository repository;

@GetMapping
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
    return (List<Student>) repository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping
public String createStudent() {
    return "created";
}

@PutMapping
public String updateStudent() {
    return "updated";
}

@DeleteMapping
public String deleteStudent() {
    return "deleted";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing slash in annotation, it should look like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {
   ...
}
```